# Display a large csv file in PyQt Table View

Tags: python, csv, pyqt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

Im trying to display the Master File Table of an NTFS Volume ,in a PyQt Application . I have extracted the MFT and converted into a csv file , now i wish to display the data in a tabular form using PyQt Table View. The program runs perfectly without any error but displays nothing.

The CSV file has a size of 300 Mb.

right now this is what my code looks like :

```
try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.tableView = QtGui.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("tableView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.actionOpen = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(_fromUtf8(":/icons/open.jpg")), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionOpen.setIcon(icon)
        self.actionOpen.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionOpen"))


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionExit, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("triggered(bool)")), MainWindow.close)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.actionOpen, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"),self.ExtractMFT)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
        self.actionOpen.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "Open", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))


    def ExtractMFT(self, root = None):
        if root == None:
            root = "\\\\.\C:"

        FileName = "MFT-EXtracted"
        CSVName = "MFT-EXtracted.csv"
        print 1
        Control=subprocess.Popen(["icat",root,"0-128-1",">",FileName],shell =True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        Control.wait()
        print 2
        print Control.stdout.read()
        if Control.stderr == None:
            print 3
            #Control=subprocess.Popen(["python","analyzeMFT.py","-f",FileName,"-o",CSVName],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            #Control.wait()
            print 5
            print Control.stdout.read()
            if Control.stderr == None:
                self.loadCsv(CSVName)


    def loadCsv(self, fileName):
        # The problem persist in this function. The items being appended to the 
        # model are not being displayed by the tableView , infact the tableView 
        # is empty nothing come's up. 
        header = False
        header_data=[]
        data=[]
        print 6
        se2 = 0
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        with open(fileName, "rb") as fileInput:
            for row in csv.reader(fileInput):
                if header == True:
                    items = [
                    QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                    for field in row
                ]
                    model.appendRow(items)
                elif header ==False:
                    for field in row:
                        items = [
                        field
                        for field in row
                        ]
                        header_data.append(items)
                     header == True

           print 7
           self.tableView.setModel(model)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow() # <-- Instantiate QMainWindow object.
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    app.exec_()



main()
```

The CSV file that i intend to load has 300,000+ rows in it, so is their an efficient way to load data into the view. So that less system resources are used.

Comment: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: can you narrow down the problem, or should we debug for you? By judicious use of print statements you can probably tell us where the code *should* be doing something but isn't.

Comment: @Schollii : I have edited the code and removed the irrelevant code.

Comment: See my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588584/pyqt-qtableview-prohibitibily-slow-when-scrolling-with-large-data-sets/31591015#31591015

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you want to just load the parts of file that the user can see (plus a little bit on either side so you can determine when to load more). You should be able to apply the techniques discussed in [Big Tables page](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq07-big-tables.html). There may be other similar tutorials or discussions that you can find via google.

Comment: @rene Looks like qt docs have moved. I have updated the link.

Comment: Thanks @schollii for the quick reply back! Cheers