# Changing a PYQT/Pandas code to use numpy instead of pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a QtableView which is using Pandas Model as its model, but the resulting table is too slow to scroll/manipulate.

I read here [PyQt QTableView prohibitively slow when scrolling with large data sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588584/pyqt-qtableview-prohibitively-slow-when-scrolling-with-large-data-sets/31591015#31591015) that numpy was much faster than pandas, so I'm trying to implement numpy instead.

The problem I'm running into is, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent of ***loc*** in numpy. I can deal with all the ilocs that pandas was using (since that is just row/column numbers), but how do I let the numpy model know, for instance, that I would like to change the value of the row which has the index (in my case, the second column value) as 73563.

Similarly, I receive a message in the form of JSON, which has data as (Column1: Value1, Column2:Value2... etc), based on which I updated my table values by simply passing the column name and new value as follows

```
    for col in data.keys():
        self._data.loc[key,col] = data[col]
```

where key is the index value. Now I can pass the row number instead of index value, but how do I take care of the *col* matching part?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand the question, but maybe [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) helps ...